# using aws sdk for java in Jruby

Tags: amazon-web-services, jruby, aws-sdk, jrubyonrails

I have an app which uses the amazon web services.The app is installed with jruby on rails.I have to use java aws sdk for calling amazon web services.

Can u help me as in how to include aws sdk in my app and use it

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to put the jar files for the sdk inside your /lib/java folder, and make sure to include them in your classpath.  ([See this example](http://www.ozmox.com/2010/11/20/use-ms-sql-server-with-rails-3-and-jruby/) on including a JDBC driver, same concept.)

Then to use the objects in Ruby you just instantiate them like you normally would:

```
require 'java'

myAwsObj = com.amazon.aws.class.someMethod('some','params')
```

You can visit the [JRuby Kenai site](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/CallingJavaFromJRuby#Beware_of_Java_generics) for examples of calling Java from inside Ruby.  Obviously the package name above I made up, but you should get the idea from there.  The Kenai page also has lots of other examples and gotchas.